# How to get the average data of acummulated precipitation

Tags: netcdf4, cdo-climate

I'm really new to this CDO thing and I feel awkward.

I have been working with netcdf files that have daily precipitation data and I would like to perform these calculations with CDO

- First calculate the moving sum of precipitation using a 5-day window.

-Then calculate the annual maximum of the sliding sum for each year.

-And finally, calculate the 20-year average of those values

Comment: I don't quite follow the question. What does this mean? "5 consecutive days where the accumulated precipitation is maximum" What is the maximum in this case? It sounds like you mean annual maximum, but in that case I don't understand why you would have 5 consecutive days of the annual maximum, which sounds impossible unless there is something strange in the way the satellite precipitation is calculated

Comment: It is actually the accumulated precipitation for 5 consecutive days. The Rx5 index that comes from the Expert Team (ET) on Climate Change Detection. I have corrected the question, it would be to calculate the accumulated of 5 consecutive days in particular.

Comment: It may happen that more than one event occurs where precipitation accumulates for 5 consecutive days, then one of those values will be the maximum precipitation accumulated in 5 consecutive days during that particular year.

Sorry, I'm very nervous to bother you with this question, I hope I have been able to explain better and I'm sorry for the problems

Comment: Ah, this question has been edited since I posted my answer and now asks for something completely different!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything is in a single file, the following approach, where all 3 calcs are chained, should work:

```
cdo -timmean -yearmax -runsum,5 infile outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Logged on to find the question has been completely changed, so I deleted my original answer.

Robert Wilson's answer now addresses your new question perfectly, I just wanted to add that as an alternative to using the running mean, you might also think to just do simple pentad averages that are commonly employed in meteorology. In that case you would want to do

```
cdo timselmean,5 in.nc out.nc
```

this gives you pentad averages.  Then you can get the max pentad value and take the twenty year average in the same way as Robert shows, thus piping the three commands you get

```
cdo -timmean -yearmax -timselmean,5 in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Yes, excuse me Adrian, I am working with the performance of a satellite compared to observed data. So I am calculating that at a given time of the year there are 5 consecutive days where the accumulated precipitation is maximum in the data observed at a particular spatial point.
So what I do is look for that same date for the satellite data and perform the accumulation.

As I have a period of 20 years I want to make an average of the precipitation in 20 years, the problem is that I did not know how to do it in my netcdf file

Comment: I just edited the question, it's just that I had a hard time putting into words what I was trying to do. I hope now you can understand better!

Comment: Can you explain how you can get 5 consecutive days of maximum precipitation? I don't follow how that can actually occur in one year never mind every year

Comment: It is actually the accumulated precipitation for 5 consecutive days. The Rx5 index that comes from the Expert Team (ET) on Climate Change Detection

Comment: Your update just now is equally confusing. Is your question really "How do I calculate the 20-year average of annual maximum precipitation in a 5-day window"?

Comment: It may happen that more than one event occurs where precipitation accumulates for 5 consecutive days, then one of those values will be the maximum precipitation accumulated in 5 consecutive days during that particular year.

Sorry, I'm very nervous to bother you with this question, I hope I have been able to explain better and I'm sorry for the problems

Comment: Things are no clearer, unfortunately. Your question currently defines an event as one where precipitation accumulates for 5 consecutive days, but you want the average of 20 years of those events. But you say these events occur more than once a year. How do you get 20 events in 20 years if more than 1 occurs per year?

Comment: I am looking for the event where this accumulated precipitation is the highest during the year. I would choose only 1 event per year, that is why I seek to calculate the average value

Comment: So. You want to first calculate the rolling sum of preciptation using a 5-day window. Then you want to calculate the annual maximum of the rolling sum for each year. And finally you want to calculate the 20 year mean of those values? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I really know how to excuse my clumsiness!

Comment: Can you please rewrite the question to reflect this?